# Trigger same macro with different command button with Button properties

Tags: excel, vba

As the subject suggest, I have build a macro that will need a variable input

```
Sub GetFile(Account as String)
```

Currently i am setting multiple sub to call the script and assign them to different command buttons

```
Sub AC1_File
    Call GetFile("Account1")
end sub

Sub AC2_File
    Call GetFile("Account2")
end sub
```

And the list go on

I am trying to not make my code too long (as i got double digits accounts),
is it possible for me code to get properties of the commandbutton name and use it instead of Account1,2,3...?

Something like below?

```
Call GetFile(triggering-commandbutton.name)
```

Comment: Just to check, these are ActiveX command buttons, as opposed to a Form Control button? With a Form Control button, you could use [`Application.Caller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller). More complex with ActiveX, but doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Form Controls

In a normal module add a procedure with no arguments:

```
Public Sub Button_Click()
    GetFile Application.Caller
End Sub
```

This code will pick up the button name and pass it to the `GetFile` procedure.

```
Sub GetFile(Account As String)
    MsgBox "Account Name is " & Account
End Sub
```

So now all you need to do is name your buttons *Account1*, *Account2*, etc..

---

### ActiveX Controls

If you're using ActiveX controls you can use a class to capture the click event.

Create a class module and name it `clsButtonClick`.
Add this code to the class module:

```
Public WithEvents AccountBtn As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub AccountBtn_Click()
    MsgBox AccountBtn.Name & " on " & AccountBtn.Parent.Name
    GetFile AccountBtn.Name
End Sub
```

At the very top of a normal module add this line:

```
Public colBtns As New Collection
```

And add this code to the module:

```
Public Sub Initialize_Buttons()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim btnEvnt As clsButtonClick
    Dim obj As OLEObject

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each obj In wrkSht.OLEObjects
            If TypeName(obj.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
                Set btnEvnt = New clsButtonClick
                Set btnEvnt.AccountBtn = obj.Object
                colBtns.Add btnEvnt
            End If
        Next obj
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

This will go through each sheet in your workbook and give any ActiveX command buttons the click event from the class module.
Update the `Initialize_Buttons` procedure if you need to limit it to a specific sheet, or specific buttons on a sheet.

Finally call the `Initialize_Buttons` code in the `Workbook_Open` event in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Answer (score 0):

You can create many commandbuttons as ActiveX controller, then write VBA like below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call GetFile("Account1")
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Call GetFile("Account2")
End Sub
```

Comment: the sub or function of GetFile() is actuallly written inside the command button or inside the ThisWorkBook object ?

Comment: @gumuruh OP didn't mention about that.  But, usually I will write them in a normal `Module`.