# Assigning dynamic code to multiple buttons

Tags: excel, vba

Firstly, sorry for the poor statement of the problem.

Here is the issue. Using a macro, I created multiple buttons and now there is a button in each cell along the last column of the used range. However, none of them is assigned a macro.

What I want to do is to come up with dynamic code that will make those buttons to conduct the desired task so that I can avoid writing a macro for each and every single of them. In other words, what I wish to learn is;

If button `i` is clicked then do stuff.

Comment: @BigBen Well, it's not that I do not want to, but it's just that I am not able to as I haven't done it yet, but I know how to do it. Basically, in a worksheet other than the one where the buttons are placed, I have IDs, the date and some balance. IDs are duplicated many times as they are populated by the date, yet balance differentiates for every different date value. What I want is to make all buttons to be able to give the user a chart using the before mentioned information set. And I want to avoid specifying the information range for all buttons, which is humanly impossible to do anyway.

Comment: How do the buttons relate to ID/date? Is each button a different ID and/or date and/or combo?

Comment: @BigBen Each button is named and captioned after the relevant ID- e.g. "btn140768389".

Comment: Are they ActiveX or Form Control buttons?

Comment: I'd suggest to do it the other way round. Use one button and decide what to do based on the activecell.

Comment: @BigBen No, they aren't.

Comment: @Storax Is what I desire to do is impossible or is it just that what you suggest is simply easier?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase that question - which are they, ActiveX or Form Control buttons? Or are you creating shapes that you assign macros to?

Comment: @BigBen they are created by the following line of code: btn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height). t is a variable for the cell reference and employing a loop I add as many buttons as I needed.

Comment: Then it's a Form Control button.

Comment: Î think it's easier but you don't really tell what the problem is. Right now it seems to be an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trigger same macro with different command button with button properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739815/trigger-same-macro-with-different-command-button-with-button-properties)

Comment: @BigBen I will study it thank you.

Comment: No problem. Sounds like `Application.Caller` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to add click event handlers (methods that execute when you click the button), it's enough to define them in a module (very important!) and then assign the method name to `OnAction` of your button. See sample code below:

```
Sub test()
    Dim btn As Button
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim t As Range
    ' button will be placed in A1 cell
    Set t = Cells(1, 1)
    Set btn = Worksheets("Arkusz1").Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    With btn
        ' here we assign an event handler
        .OnAction = "BtnAction"
        .Caption = "My button"
        .Name = "MyBtn"
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Above code is defined in a sheet, and the code in a module (event handler):

```
Sub BtnAction()
    MsgBox "Hello world!"
End Sub
```